# Anywhere to convert between eth and eos

Tags: accounts

Any place to convert between eth and eos or btc easily and without submit the Id so everyone can convert from one coin to another and no need to do this by submit a lot of document.

Comment: This question is not specific to EOS.IO technology and does not belong here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [BancorX updates](https://blog.bancor.network/bancor-progress-update-november-2018-858676fbe666)? Here's the platform: [BancorX Liquidity Network](https://eos.bancor.network/?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=november-progress&utm_campaign=progressupdate2018)